# Expanding Flash Storage with SDXC

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, storage, raid

I see on a Macbook Pro, you can expand your current storage space with SDHC or SDXC. Being a Linux user I know you can use RAID to expand storage with 2 disk, so storage looks like 1 HD. However, most of the time this setup happens when NO O/S is currently installed on 1 of the 2 storage units.

Would is be possible to expand my storage from the current internal flash storage that host the O/S to a SDXC card, so the storage virtually looks like 1 hard-drive from the mac os desktop?

This should be resolved software wise, however I do not think Disk Utility can accomplish or this can be naturally accomplish with out erasing the OS 1st(Which I do not want to do).

Comment: First of all [diskpart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskpart) is a Windows utility not OS X and secondly the Read/Write time differences between the SSD and a SDHC or SDXC card is enough that I would even try to create a RAID between them, even if possible.  If you need extra storage then just use the SDHC or SDXC card as is, an additional volume to be able to read/write to. IMO, and as a general rule, all devices within a RAID should all be the same type and size.

Comment: I would never trust any long-term data to an SD card of any description anyway. I use hundreds of them for work & the fail-rate is alarming.

Comment: Yes I know that diskpart is a Windows utility. I just put the wrong utility.  You could technically use diskpart as well if you want to get nitty gritty  about it.Anyways, SD card with a cloud backup is worth the risk. I guess this isn't a place to ask a question like this...

Comment: The file format for SDXC is typically ExFAT. However, if you want a Time Machine volume to include the SDXC with backups, then the SDXC needs to be reformatted to Mac OS Extended (Journaled). Otherwise, the Time Machine volume will not acknowledge the SDXC.

Answer (score 1):

The only viable options for RAID using just 2 drives would be RAID 0 or 1.

RAID 1 wouldn't increase your storage, so 0 is the only remaining choice.

Even if you could RAID an internal fixed drive to a removable SD card (& without first formatting both), the drive would only be 'whole' so long as both were present (& still functional.)
If either drive was missing (or broken) the entire RAID would be irrecoverable.

Trusting an entire RAID to the vagaries of an SD card would be playing russian roulette with your data.